# [perl]How to force perl use modules in my own path?

Tags: dbi, perl

I want to let perl use the DBI module in my own path(suppose, /home/users/zdd/perl5/lib/DBI), but the sysem also has a DBI module which is /usr/lib/perl5/lib/DBI.
when I write the following code in my script, perl use the system path be default, how to force it use the one under my path?

```
use lib './perl5/lib/DBI';
use DBI;

sub test {
....
}
```

/usr/lib/perl5/lib/DBI was added to the PATH environment variable in my bash profile, it was used by many scripts, so I can't disable it.

Comment: You have given a relative path. Are you running your script from the same location where it is present?

Comment: yes, I also try to use an absolute path, does not work either, is that mean, if two path are in hand, the script will pick the system one first?

Comment: yes, it will pick the 1st available one..

Comment: @Guru, `use lib` places the specified path at the beginning of `@INC`.  Thus this will pick the module from the user's path first, if it actually finds it there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file for the main `DBI` module is in `./perl5/lib`.  So your path is not pointing to it.

The `DBI` folder contains sub-modules of `DBI`, e.g. `DBI::Foo` (the `::` in module names is a representation of your module directory structure).

Try using `./perl5/lib` as your library instead.

Also, using a relative path will fail if the current directory is not what you think it is.  If you are in doubt, have your script [call `cwd`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) to see what the current directory is.

For debugging purposes, it may be helpful to use:

```
no lib '[main Perl module library path here]';
```

That way you can be sure you are only using your custom module path.  Any failure to find a module will cause an error, rather than silently using the system version.

**Update:** For more information, see [Perldoc on `use lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html).  Perl *will* use the library that you have specified first.  If it does not, that indicates it is not actually finding the module in the location you have given.

Comment: try that, it still use the system one.

Comment: @zdd, are you sure the current directory is what you think it is?  Try using the absolute path. I know you said you already tried the absolute path.  However, that wouldn't have worked for the reason stated in my answer.

Comment: @zdd, see also the update to my answer.  This will work if you are specifying the correct location.

Comment: I see your answer and removed DBI from the path, but it still use the system module.

Comment: @zdd, if this is not working, then the `use lib` statement is not pointing to what you think it is, or the DBI module is not there. For testing purposes, you can also add `no lib [system Perl lib path here]`.  That will guarantee that it does not take anything from the system library.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what dan1111 suggested, I would also recommend you print out `@INC` (just before your `use DBI` statement) and dump `%INC` (just after your `use DBI` statement) to see what your script is doing. That may help you debug the issue.